# How to separate rake tasks between 2 servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, puma, rake-task

I have 2 different remote servers for my Rails application.To deploy im using capistrano. First - staging, second production. To run puma server each server uses their own comand, so on local machine im using next:

STAGING:

```
run("bundle exec puma -C /var/www/snapship/shared/config/puma.rb --daemon")
```

PROD:

```
sudo :systemctl, "start puma.target"
```

When I deploy my application i write: cap staging deploy or cap production deploy. How can I let the Rails app know which puma start it should use? Because I cant check Rails.env on local machine (it always development)

UPDATE:: (Capfile)

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/puma"
require "capistrano/puma/nginx"
require "capistrano/puma/jungle"
require "sshkit/sudo"
require "whenever/capistrano"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Deploy.rb

```
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'snapship'
set :pty, true
set :repo_url, 'git@gitlab.com:snapship/snapship-backend.git'
set :user, ENV['USER'] || 'deploy'
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb', '.env', '.rbenv-vars')
set :linked_dirs, %w(tmp/pids tmp/sockets log public/uploads)

# rbenv plugin setup
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, File.read('.ruby-version').strip
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, fetch(:rbenv_map_bins, []).push('foreman')

# bundle plugin setup
set :bundle_bins, fetch(:bundle_bins, []).push('foreman')

# puma plugin setup
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"


before :deploy, "deploy:run_tests"
after "deploy:publishing", "foreman:export"
after "deploy:publishing", "systemd:update"
after "deploy:publishing", "systemd:enable"

set :migration_servers, -> { release_roles(fetch(:migration_role)) }
```

Also 2 files staging and production for each deploy.

Comment: How does your capistrano config and the environment setup look like? Do you have `stage` or `rails_env` defined?

Comment: @spickermann check update pls

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
# in deploy.rb
# define stages
set :stages, %w(staging production)
# then get the current stage
set :my_var_env, Proc.new { fetch :stage }
```

then run `cap staging deploy`

I also use the `gem 'capistrano3-puma'` which gives me tasks like

```
cap staging|production puma:[start|stop|restart|status]
```